# error "running 'zip' failed" in compile R package

Tags: r

When i compile source file,

```
 Rcmd  INSTALL  --build e:\gongxiang\A3_0.9.2.tar.gz     

 Welcome at Mon Nov 18 19:19:33 2013     
 * installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library'     
 * installing *source* package 'A3' ...     
 ** package 'A3' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked     
 ** R     
 ** data     
 ** inst     
 ** preparing package for lazy loading     
 ** help     
 *** installing help indices     
 ** building package indices     
 ** testing if installed package can be loaded     

 Welcome at Mon Nov 18 19:19:34 2013     

 Goodbye at  Mon Nov 18 19:19:35 2013     
 * MD5 sums     
 running 'zip' failed     
 * DONE (A3)     

 Goodbye at  Mon Nov 18 19:19:35 2013
```

how to fix the error `running 'zip' failed`  ,maybe something is wrong .
when i type cmd,then  type zip --version,i get error.
i have installed 7zip.exe in `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` to extract zip files,which zip extract will be installed?
here is my session info:

sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

i have solved it by installing  RTOOLS and set path when installing .

Comment: 1) Could you add some system details please?  I think you're on windows and r 3.02 based on the code but giving more details on your setup like your rtools version may help track down the issue.  2) Can you try compiling a blank package to determine whether the problem relates to your code or your system.  3) Can you try using the zip function on a file to determiine whether whether this is a general system issue or a system issue at build time?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a config issue. Do you have zip on your path? Check by pressing `Windows + R`, type `cmd`. Then, type `zip --version`. If it gives an error, reinstall a Zip extractor and att it to your `PATH` variable.